# anybody know what song this is?

Tags: chord-progressions

I can't seem to find out what song. All's I really have is roughly the chord progression that I can work out. Seems to be a

vi-V-vi-I

Or

Am Am GM - Am Am CM -

If it's in c major/ a minor key. It has a female singer and guitar, kind of like 90s pop. Maybe England or Europe but popular in u.s. In 90s roughly. Don't really remember any lyrics. Sorry not much to go on I guess unless you happen to know it and strum it out and recognize it. Seem like this is only way ill figure it out. Or if I happen to hear it again randomly.

Comment: Music Fans may give better information than here.